# Get value of the date time input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to alert the value of the date time input filed, but I get error "datetimepicker is not a function", the jQuery link I use

```js
var time_start = $('#datetimepicker1').val();
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();

$(document).on('change', '#datetimepicker1', function() {
  time_start = $(this).val();
})

$(document).on('click', '#btn_ok', function() {
  alert(time_start);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="form-inline">
  <label style="padding-right: 10px">Từ</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker1" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker1" />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker1" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br>
  <label style="padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px">đến</label>
  <div class="input-group date" id="datetimepicker2" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input" data-target="#datetimepicker2" />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#datetimepicker2" data-toggle="datetimepicker">
      <div class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I fix?

Comment: Firstly, what input field? Secondly, you don't appear to have included the datetimepicker library in the page, hence the error

Comment: A datetimepicker is not included in jQuery. You need to use a jQuery plugin that does this. For example [https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker)

Comment: jQueryUI has a datepicker, if that's what you're trying to use then please read the documentation about how to use it correctly: https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ . If you're trying to use some other date/time picker then clearly you will need to include the relevant JavaScript (and maybe CSS) file for that library in your page. The error is telling you that it cannot find the function you're trying to call. The most likely reason for that is that either you used the wrong function name, or you didn't include the code for that function in your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function for the jquery ui datepicker is `datepicker`, not `datetimepicker`. Also you were attaching the date time picker functionality to a div rather than to the input field. I have added an `onSelect` event, which will be called every time a date is selected in the calendar.

```js
$('#datetimepicker1').datepicker({
  onSelect: function(dateText) {
    alert(dateText);
  }
});

$(document).on('click', '#btn_ok', function () {
   alert($('#datetimepicker1').val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<div class="form-inline">
    <label style="padding-right: 10px">Từ</label>
    <div class="input-group date" data-target-input="nearest">
         <input type="text" id="datetimepicker1" class="form-control datetimepicker-input">
    </div>
    <button id="btn_ok">Submit</button>
</div>
```